# PHP Session isn't recognizable from Web Browser but is from Eclipse Ide Browser

Tags: php, eclipse, session

I'm trying to access a session variable I declared in Eclipse and when I call the variable from a Web Browser, I get the error that the **session variable** is **undefined**.

But when I use the built-in Eclipse Browser everything works fine and the session variable is returned.

I have `session_start` at the beginning of all the pages too. How is the Safari/Chrome browsers different from the Eclipse IDE browser?

I get this response on the Eclipse IDE:

```
array(2) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["email"]=> string(24) "samboabubakar5@gmail.com" }
```

But I get below error when running from a Web Browser:

> ERRNO: 8 TEXT: Undefined index: user_id LOCATION: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/auction_new/php/user.php, line 176

Comment: Could you post that line, 176? :)

Comment: yes here it is: $user_id = $_SESSION ['user_id'];

Comment: Have you 'session_start()' in the top of your user.php file? And please put var_dump($_SESSION) before line no. 176.

Comment: so i have this at the top of the user.php file:
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
and this is the result of var_dump($_SESSION) :
array(0) { } @pedrouan

Comment: Thank you. So session is working well. And it's empty. How to you fill your session variable? Where do you put user info into the session. Somewhere you have to have '$_SESSION ['user_id'] = something' stated

Comment: hey thanks so much! so i have the this in a login function that's called earlier:
$_SESSION ['user_id'] = $id;
but i do the login only in eclipse and not in a web browser could that be the issue?

Comment: I feel quite blind if I don't see all your related code. Yes, because you have to simulate the same as you are doing in IDE.

Comment: yes so that was the issue i got it to work by simulating the same situation as the ide. Thanks a lot

Comment: If any issues, just update your question and let me know about it